# Replace URL fields by Uri with Jackson

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jackson

I have some objects with URLs in fields for example like this :

```kotlin
class A {

    val url1 : URL
    val url2 : URL
    val urls : ArrayList<URL>

}
```

I would like to replace URLs by Uri, but I've use Jackson and SQLite to serialise objects and store them in DB. So if I change the type, I can't retrieve stored objects.

So, I've implemented Custom Deserialise like that :

```kotlin
class UriDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Uri>(Uri::class.java) {

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Uri {

        return Uri.parse(p?.valueAsString)
    }

}

class UriArrayDeserializer : StdDeserializer<ArrayList<Uri>>(ArrayList::class.java) {

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): ArrayList<Uri> {

        val uriArray = arrayListOf<Uri>()

        p?.nextToken()
        while (p?.currentToken != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

            val uri = Uri.parse(p?.text)
            uriArray.add(uri)

            p?.nextToken()
        }

        return uriArray
    }


}
```

And then I've added UriDeserializer for fields in my class :

```kotlin
class A {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = UriDeserializer::class)
    val url1 : Uri

    @JsonDeserialize(using = UriDeserializer::class)
    val url2 : Uri

    @JsonDeserialize(using = UriArrayDeserializer::class)
    val urls : ArrayList<Uri>

}
```

With this code, I can deserialize my old objects, but now I can't serialise new ones, I get this error :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.package.A["url2"]->android.net.Uri$StringUri["canonicalUri"])
```

Do I have to implement Custom Serialises too ? Maybe there is a simplest way to replace URL by Uri ?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the checked answer, I've found the solution to my problem : So I've used a MixIn interface with Custom Serializer and Deserializer.

```kotlin
@JsonSerialize(using = UriSerializer::class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = UriDeserializer::class)
interface UriMixIn

class UriDeserializer : StdDeserializer<Uri>(Uri::class.java) {

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Uri {
        return Uri.parse(p?.valueAsString)
    }
}

class UriSerializer : StdSerializer<Uri>(Uri::class.java) {

    override fun serialize(value: Uri?, gen: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
        gen?.writeString(value?.toString())
    }
}
```

Then, I've added UriMixIn wherever it needed like :

```kotlin
val jackson = jacksonObjectMapper()
jackson.addMixIn(Uri::class.java, UriMixIn::class.java)
```

This solution works like a charm ! Thanks a lot for your help, have a great day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement custom serialiser or use `MixIn` feature.

To understand why, we need to take look how [android.net.Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/Uri) class was implemented. We can check sources at [Android Googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java). Quick look and we noticed that `parse` method returns `StringUri` object:

```
public static Uri parse(String uriString) {
    return new StringUri(uriString);
}
```

It is mentioned about in internal documentation:

> This class aims to do as little up front work as possible. To
>   accomplish
>       that, we vary the implementation depending on what the user passes in.
>       For example, we have one implementation if the user passes in a
>       URI string (StringUri) and another if the user passes in the
>       individual components (OpaqueUri)

Let's analyse further. `StringUri` is a `private static class` which does not look like a regular `POJO`. From other side, `canonicalUri` field with which you have a problem returns `this` in case `Uri` is built from `String` so this is a reason we need a custom serialiser or using [MixIn Feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) we can ignore this `field/getter`.

This is a very common problem when `Jackson` is used to `serialise` not regular `POJO` objects. Similar questions:

1. [Why Jackson JSON mapping exception when Serializing/Deserializing Geometry type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258275/why-jackson-json-mapping-exception-when-serializing-deserializing-geometry-type)
2. [Serializing/deserializing exceptions without stack trace using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530206/serializing-deserializing-exceptions-without-stack-trace-using-jackson)
3. [Is there a built in mechanism within org.kohsuke.github to serialize GHRepository objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871185/is-there-a-built-in-mechanism-within-org-kohsuke-github-to-serialize-ghrepositor)
4. [Jackson/Gson serialize and deserialize JavaFX Properties to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455801/jackson-gson-serialize-and-deserialize-javafx-properties-to-json)
5. [Java InvalidDefinitionException when serializing object with jackson databind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305131/java-invaliddefinitionexception-when-serializing-object-with-jackson-databind)

Some examples, how to use `MixIn`:

1. [Make Jackson serializer override specific ignored fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763305/make-jackson-serializer-override-specific-ignored-fields)
2. [Custom Jackson Serializer for a specific type in a particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252918/custom-jackson-serializer-for-a-specific-type-in-a-particular-class)
3. [What is equivalent code settings for @JSonIgnore annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939333/what-is-equivalent-code-settings-for-jsonignore-annotation)
4. [Jackson parse json with unwraping root, but without ability to set @JsonRootName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568867/jackson-parse-json-with-unwraping-root-but-without-ability-to-set-jsonrootname)

Also, you can use `MixIn` feature to register `serialiser/deserialiser` globally for `Uri` type. In that case you do not need to implement `UriArrayDeserializer` class.

See:

1. [Jackson – Custom Serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization#on-mapper)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time ! If I understood correctly, I can make a custom serializer and a custom deserializer, then I use both in a MixIn interface, and then my ```jacksonObjectMapper``` can serialize/deserialize all my ```Uri``` including ```array``` ?

Comment: @Ady, yes. That's right. You need to register serializer and deserializer globally. You can do this by using `MixIn` and registering them on type level or by registering it on `ObjectMapper` level.